# SQL SSRS and Default Values Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssrs

I am creating a stored procedure with a corresponding default value. 
It is using a default value of 2018 below.

```
create procedure rpt.FinanceReport
    @AccountYearParam int = 2018
as
select * from FinanceTable where AccountYear = @AccountYearParam
```

How do I pass the default Value into an SSRS report? So when the user selects nothing for parameter, it will display 2018.

"Using Null values", does not work, since Null will product a nothing.
I want the SSRS report to display all values for 2018, if user selects nothing for parameter.

Comment: How to set default value in SSRS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-change-or-delete-default-values-for-a-report-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind building the query as an expression (set the Query type to text and use the expression button to define the query), you can do something like this:

```
="EXEC MYPROC @PARAM=" &
 iif(isnothing(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value),
     "DEFAULT",
     Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value)
```

This just says if the parameter is Nothing (null) use the keyword DEFAULT, otherwise use the parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle nulls inside the stored procedure with an isnull() like this:

```
create procedure rpt.FinanceReport
    @AccountYearParam int 
as

set @AccountYearParam = isnull(@AccountYearParam, 2018)
--
select * from FinanceTable where AccountYear = @AccountYearParam
```

and if you want to get really fancy, you can use this (it will return the current year):

```
create procedure rpt.FinanceReport
    @AccountYearParam int 
as

set @AccountYearParam = isnull(@AccountYearParam, datepart(year, getdate()))
--
select * from FinanceTable where AccountYear = @AccountYearParam
```

You can also handle it in the where clause, although this method might be considerably slower:

```
create procedure rpt.FinanceReport
    @AccountYearParam int 
as
--
select * from FinanceTable where AccountYear = isnull(@AccountYearParam, datepart(year, getdate()))
```